# Center AnythingSlider with hidden overflow on both sides

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, anythingslider

My goal is to have the slider 1280px wide and centered on the page. I would like the edges of the content to have hidden overflow on both sides. For example I want the center of content to always stay in the center of the page with each side being cut off as the browser is resized, with no horizontal scroll bar appearing.

Is there a straightforward way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up with a somewhat interesting solution that worked for me in (at least) Chrome, Firefox, and Safari where I tested it. It may be slightly hacky, but the result was cool.

So here's what I did: I put a `.wrapper` with a width of `1280px`. The margin is `0 auto` *except* the left margin which is where it all happens. The left margin needs to be set to *half* of the `div` width. In this case that would be `640px`. However, because it must overflow outside of the left screen it must be set to a negative number (i.e. `-640px`). Then in order to reverse that effect when the screen is larger then screen a `left:50%` pushed it over the correct amount. Obviously in order for the `margin:0 auto` to actually work, the `position` must be set to `relative` (or `absolute` if you would like).

```
.wrapper { width:1280px;
           margin:0 auto 0 -640px; 
           position:relative; 
           left:50% 
         }
```

*the one problem*
I found one problem with it, though. Because we are using negative margin, it pushes the div to the left to where one can not see if their screen or browser window is too small. Let me know if this is a problem and makes it to where it doesn't work for you.

Comment: wow this seems to work great. I wasted a lot of time prior to this playing around with different settings. Thanks!

Comment: What was your solution for smaller screens? Just curious for now but I may run into a similar issue

Comment: Glad this worked! Honestly, I don't have a solution for smaller screens, but I would mess with it some more if you needed it for smaller screens.

Answer (score 1):

Add this css class

```
  .overflowbothsides{
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
  -o-transform: translateX(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

solution with code and example
[enter link description here](http://jsbin.com/ceniw/1/edit?html,css,output)